# When I click the button after 5 seconds it will turn green then will return to its former color

Tags: qt, button, timer, qml

When I click the button after 5 seconds it will turn green and then will return to its former color. I try to do it with timer function but it doesn't work. In QML Language

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: PS If you want this in QML code you should remove the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, but it's working using a Timer in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Timer {
        id: myTimer
            interval: 5000; repeat: false
            onTriggered: myButton.background.color = "blue"
        }

    Button {
        id: myButton
        x: 100
        y: 100
        text: "my button"
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
        }

        onClicked: {
            myButton.background.color = "green"
            myTimer.start();
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    }
}
```